# Show/hide content in expandable collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with two cells. I made cells expand/collapse by select(didSelectItemAtIndexPath). Cell contains additional views which should became visible in expanded mode and hidden in collapsed. My code work well if I play with expanded cell, but if I have expanded cell and tap on collapsed the expanded cell change their size but additional view stay visible. Maybe it  will be easy to understand looking on the gif.
Good scenario:

1. click first cell = expand it
2. click first cell again = collapse it and hide image view

Bag scenario:

1. click first cell = expand it
2. click second cell = expand second cell & collapse first cell but additional image view on first cell still visible
3. click second cell again = collapse second cell and hide their content. additional image view on first cell still visible

[image]

Here is `cell` code:

```
class ExerciseSetCell: BaseCell {

// timer
let timerButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "timer"), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)
    button.alpha = 0
    return button
}()

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    addSubview(timerButton)
    timerButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(25)
        make.height.equalTo(25)
        make.bottomMargin.equalTo(-7)
        make.centerX.equalTo(self)
    }
}
```

}

Here is my `collectionViewController` code:

```
class ExerciseDetailVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var exercise: Exercise?
let exerciseSetCell = ExerciseSetCell()
private let setCell = "ExerciseSetCell"
private var expandedCellIndex = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.registerClass(ExerciseSetCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: setCell)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(setCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExerciseSetCell
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ExerciseSetCell

    if expandedCellIndex == indexPath.item {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
            cell.weightView.alpha = 0
            cell.timerButton.alpha = 0
        })
        expandedCellIndex = -1

    } else {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            cell.weightView.alpha = 1
            cell.timerButton.alpha = 1
        })

        expandedCellIndex = indexPath.item
    }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if expandedCellIndex == indexPath.item {
        return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 200)
    }
    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 60)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}
```

Comment: is it ready solution?

Comment: @Zhan I have choose another way how to do it with table view and number of rows in section. Shortly I just play with number or rows in expanded/collapsed cell.

Comment: Thank you. I already found solution.